# Delphi: FormStyle:fsStayOnTop.InputQuery is in thread and BEHIND a Form

Tags: multithreading, delphi

How to fix it? FormStyle:fsStayOnTop. I call Input Query in a thread, but it appears behind a main form or is not visible!

I dynamically create ZipForge in a thread.

```
procedure StartUpdating.DoPassword;
var
  S: String;
begin
  if PassSkip then
    FSkipFile := True
  else if InputQuery('Pas', FFileName, S) then
    FPassword := AnsiString(S)
  else
  begin
    PassSkip := True;
    FSkipFile := True;
    Terminate;
  end;
end;
procedure StartUpdating.ZipForgePassword(Sender: TObject; FileName: String;
  var NewPassword: AnsiString; var SkipFile: Boolean);
begin
  FFileName := FileName;
  FPassword := NewPassword;
  FSkipFile := SkipFile;
  Synchronize(DoPassword);
  FileName := FFileName;
  NewPassword := FPassword;
  SkipFile := FSkipFile;
end;
```

Even if I call this from a thread it does not help me:

```
Function TForm1.InQuery(cap1: string; cap2: string):bool;
var s:string;
begin
  if InputQuery(cap1,cap2,s) then
  begin
  ThreadUpdating.MainPas:=s;
  result:=true;
  end else result:=false;
end;
```

Comment: This is not a question. You need to provide more information, and post some actual code. It's unanswerable as you've written it.

Comment: I do this, but if the form is not fsStayOnTop all is ok

Comment: I do not know exactly, may be InputQuery is invisible

Comment: He's calling `InputQuery` from a `fsStayOnTop` form, but the `InputQuery` dialog is now behind his form.

Comment: @Ian: Great. Provide a solution.

Comment: @Ken White: i was only helping to clarify confusion over the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit (2)

The form shown by `InputQuery()` is a modal form (shown using `.ShowModal`, and Delphi's VCL is smart enough to make sure no modal form is shown behind a top-most window. Essentially calls are made to `DisableTaskWindows` and `NormalizeAllTopMosts`, the interesting one being `NormalizeAllTopMosts`: this makes sure there are no top-most windows while the modal form is shown. Those calls aren't directly made, the VCL uses a number of tricks to make it happen. The details can be found by reading the code for `TCustomForm.ShowModal`, `Forms.DisableTaskWindows`, `TApplication.WndProc` - specifically the handling of the `WM_ENABLE` message.

What needs to be known is that there appears to a bug allowing a modal form to be shown behind the Main form of the application, if the main form is top-most. This is happening on both Delphi 2010 and Delphi XE, didn't test with older versions. The test is very simple: Create a new Delphi VCL application, on `Form1` set `FormStyle=fsStayOnTop`, drop a button and in the button's OnClick do this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var s:string;
begin
  s := '';
  InputQuery('a', 'b', s);
end;
```

### The fix

This should be considered a temporary fix, because clearly the design calls for top-most windows to be "degraded" before showing modal forms. If you know your main form is top-most, you should do something like this before calling `ShowModal` for anything:

```
MainForm.FormStyle := fsNormal;
try
  YourDialog.ShowModal;
finally MainForm.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
end;
```

In the particular case of `InputQuery` one can use a function similar to the following one. Please note I included the ability to turn the text editor into a password-editor, based on what the OP requested in an other question:

```
function CustomInputQuery(const Caption, Prompt: string; const Password:Boolean; var Value:string): Boolean;
var F: TForm;
    Ed: TEdit;
    Lb: TLabel;
    Bt: TButton;
    WasStayOnTop:Boolean;
begin
  F := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    F.Caption := Caption;

    Lb := TLabel.Create(F);
    Lb.Parent := F;
    Lb.Caption := Prompt;
    Lb.Left := 8;
    Lb.Top := 8;

    Ed := TEdit.Create(F);
    Ed.Parent := F;
    Ed.Left := Lb.Left + Lb.Width + 8;
    Ed.Top := 8;
    Ed.Width := 150;
    Ed.Text := Value;
    if Password then
      Ed.PasswordChar := '*';

    Bt := TButton.Create(F);
    Bt.Caption := 'Ok';
    Bt.Default := True;
    Bt.ModalResult := mrOk;
    Bt.Left := 8;
    Bt.Top := Ed.Top + Ed.Height + 8;
    Bt.Parent := F;

    Bt := TButton.Create(F);
    Bt.Caption := 'Cancel';
    Bt.Cancel := True;
    Bt.ModalResult := mrCancel;
    Bt.Left := 8 + Bt.Width + 8;
    Bt.Top := Ed.Top + Ed.Height + 8;
    Bt.Parent := F;

    F.Width := F.Width - F.ClientWidth + Ed.Left + Ed.Width + 8;
    F.Height := F.Height - F.ClientHeight + Bt.Top + Bt.Height + 8;
    F.Position := poDesktopCenter;

    WasStayOnTop := Assigned(Application.MainForm) and (Application.MainForm.FormStyle = fsStayOnTop);
    if WasStayOnTop then Application.MainForm.FormStyle := fsNormal;
    try
      if F.ShowModal = mrOk then
        begin
          Value := Ed.Text;
          Result := True;
        end
      else
        Result := False;
    finally if WasStayOnTop then Application.MainForm.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
    end;

  finally F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you imagine, it does not work! The form appear and then go back!!! No idea...

Comment: Do you have code that enforces the stay-on-top style of your other form? Something like a timer that manipulates the Z-Order of windows? And I don't understand your comments about `F.FormStyle` and `F.ShowModal`

Comment: I only have Main Menu->set window on top. fsStayOnTop + F.ShowModal present but it does not work

Comment: N8.Checked := not N8.Checked;
if N8.Checked=true then Form1.FormStyle:=fsStayOnTop else Form1.FormStyle:=fsNormal That is it

Comment: Your first paragraph is plain wrong. `InputQuery` is shown modally, and while being modal all task windows are disabled. A disabling application window calls `NormalizeAllTopMosts` for exactly this reason. Try it with a version other than D2007, and you'll see the input form will be above the stay on top form...

Comment: @Sertac, I don't understand what's wrong with the mentioned paragraph. [Here](http://fisiere.sediu.ro/altele/InputQueryBehindStayOnTop.png) is the `InputQuery` window displayed behind a `fsStayOnTop` window on Delphi 2010 and Windows 7.

Comment: @Cosmin - Then the VCL still has errors, I stand my assertion that this is not by design. The design is to normalize top most windows while showing a modal window.

Comment: @Cosmin - Would you care to look at the code in `TApplication.WndProc`, is there calls to `NormalizeAllTopMosts` and `RestoreTopMosts` in the `WM_ENABLE` case?

Comment: @Sertac, yes there are. I placed a brakepoint in there, when the modal `InputQuery` is shown an WM_ENABLE message is received, and the handler ("unrolling" all the `IF`'s) does `Default` followed by `NormalizeAllTopMosts`. After the `InputQuery` form is shown WM_ENABLED is again received, and it does `RestoreTopMosts` followed by `Default`.

Comment: @Cosmin - Thank you very much for looking. In that case, I think, *normalization* is simply b0rked again (it doesn't do its job). I'd suggest maxfax a simple `Application.ModalPopupMode := pmAuto;` before the `InputQuery`, and restore it afterwards it it's necessary.

Comment: @Sertac, it's got something to do with the Main window being the top-most window. I made an other test where the Main window is not top-most and there's an other top-most window, the Modal form was shown above the top-most window, as expected. I'm not sure normalization is broken, because having an application's main window top-most doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Sertac, you should add an answer with all this info so I can delete this one.

Comment: @Cosmin - A top-most main window should stay on top of other applications' windows, not a considerate design perhaps but it might have a purpose. About adding an answer, I can suggest 'popup mode', but not having a recent version, I don't feel comfortable about going into details.

Comment: Nice one! Sorry to have bugged you this much. :)

Comment: @Sertac, bug me this way any time you get the chance. I enjoy delving into the depths of the VCL and I learned something new today. I don't work with stay-on-top forms and didn't know about all the magic the VCL is putting into making this work.

Comment: Excellent & full answer. Thanks!